# Problem using 'ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase'

Tags: 14.04, security, encryption, ecryptfs

I have 2 laptops running Ubuntu 14.04.

1>    The Toshiba supplies the mount passphrase when I run 'ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase'

2>     When I run 'ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase' the HP does not supply the mount passphrase but instead asks me to  ' sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils '.

3>     After I run 'sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils'

4>     I run 'ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase' and get:-

5>   stat: No such file or directory Usage: ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase [file] or printf "%s" "wrapping passphrase" | ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase [file]

Question:- Why the different results and what do I have to do to get my Mount passphrase from the HP?

Comment: I have the same error and i don't know how to solve it ...